# Why only one article tag it`s getting style changes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am writing a code so i can get random articles width. The website is installed on WordPress.
My php it's getting articles from WordPress server, and listing them on the page:

```
    while(have_posts()) { 
            the_post();?>
            <article id="demo" style="border:1px solid black">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            </article>
        
    <?php } 
?>
```

My script for article with id demo:

```
<script>
var x = 100/(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)+1);
document.getElementById("demo").style.width = x + "%";
</script>
```

I suppose i need to introduce a for loop in script so all articles can get this width change?

Comment: [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: `.getElementById` only returns a single element. (There should only be a single element with a given Id anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can do the following  (assuming you've changed `id="demo"` to `class="demo"`)

```
// This fetches all elements with the class "demo" and iterates through them
$('.demo').each(function () {
    // Let's generate the new width for this specific element
    let newWidth = 100/(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)+1) + '%';

    // In here, "this" is the current element and we pass it into jQuery to get
    // a jQuery object back just to simplify things
    $(this).css({width: newWidth});
});
```

You can read more about `.each()` in [the manual for jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Console gave me this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @NickDruta - Then the question becomes: are you actually using the jQuery-library? Or did you just add that tag to your question? If you do, then do you include the library before or after run this code?

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks a lot i will edit the post, so anyone can see this answer.

Comment: @NickDruta - No need to edit the post. They can see the answer fine here since you've accepted it. Leave your post "as is" instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the element via it's `ID`, an `ID` is unique, instead you should defined the `demo` as a `class`.
Then in your `js` do a `foreach` loop to go through all of the `demo` class.

---

### Learn more

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Better to recommend [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) than `getElementsByClassName` as the latter returns a live `HTMLCollection` which will lead to headaches unless a live reference to the DOM is explicitly needed.

Comment: @pilchard i don`t know jquerry, if you can help me with the code i will really appreciate this

Comment: @NickDruta - With [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), you can fetch all elements with a specific class like this: `$('.demo')`. To change the width of all elements with that class, you can do: `$('.demo').css({width: x + '%'});`

Comment: @NickDruta Working minimum version https://codepen.io/amarinediary/pen/zYKRqap?editors=1011. The `random` function output either `1` or `0`, when `0` is outputed you get `width="100%"`. You might want to change the `+1` to something else, like `+2` for example.

Comment: @amarinediary i want like it is, because i want every post to have different width like 100, 50 or 33.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson this will make everything equal, i want to be a bit different from one another

Comment: @NickDruta - I posted an answer that should solve that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i did that, but it doesn't change

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i put an image to show that

Comment: @NickDruta - Please comment on my answer under my answer so avoid confusion. You should also check the console for potential error messages.

Comment: Once again, the style is applied, tho, if your width is devided by `( 0 * 3 ) + 1` the output will be `100%` as you're dividing by `1`.

Comment: @amarinediary random function give a random number from 0 to 1(excluded), so if i multiply with 3 i get  0,1,2. Then if i add 1, i get 1,2,3, as i wanted. I tried to change to +2, and it didn`t worked. The console gave me an error, i commented it.